# ReportViewer Showing empty in vs2010

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, reporting-services

I'm calling a report from report server, the project runs successfully but the page will be empty. through development tool I can find the amount of space it is acquired.

Below is the code i'm using.

Web Config.
under system.web

```
<httpHandlers>
  <add path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" verb="*" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" validate="false"/>
</httpHandlers>
```

system.web under compilation

```
<buildProviders>
    <add extension=".rdlc" type="Microsoft.Reporting.RdlBuildProvider, Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
</buildProviders>
```

and there are some assemblies which are automatically added when the reportviewer was added to the page.

under system.webservices

```
<handlers>
  <add name="ReportViewerWebControlHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
</handlers>
```

cs page

```
int dcid = 1;
ReportViewer1.Visible = true;
ReportViewer1.ProcessingMode = Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ProcessingMode.Remote;
ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ReportServer"].ToString());
Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportParameterInfoCollection paramInfo;
System.Collections.Generic.List<Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportParameter> paramList = new System.Collections.Generic.List<Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportParameter>();
paramList.Add(new Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportParameter("DCId", dcid.ToString(), false));
ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ReportsFolder"].ToString() + "rpt_DCForm";
ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportServerCredentials = new Credentials(ConfigurationManager
                                                                     .AppSettings["ReportUserName"].ToString(), ConfigurationManager
                                                                     .AppSettings["ReportUserPwd"].ToString(), ConfigurationManager
                                                                     .AppSettings["ReportserverDomain"].ToString());

ReportViewer1.ProcessingMode = Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ProcessingMode.Local;
ReportViewer1.ServerReport.SetParameters(paramList);
paramInfo = ReportViewer1.ServerReport.GetParameters();
ReportViewer1.ServerReport.Refresh();
```

Credentials class

```
string _userName, _password, _domain;
    public Credentials(string userName, string Password, string domain)
    {
        _userName = userName;
        _password = Password;
        _domain = domain;
    }

    #region IReportServerCredentials Members

    public bool GetFormsCredentials(out System.Net.Cookie authCookie, out string userName, out string password, out string authority)
    {
        //userName = _userName;
        //password = _password;
        //authority = _domain;
        //authCookie = new System.Net.Cookie(".ASPXAUTH", ".ASPXAUTH", "/", "Domain");
        //return true;
        authCookie = null;
        userName = password = authority = null;
        return false;

    }

    public System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity ImpersonationUser
    {
        get { return null; }
    }

    public System.Net.ICredentials NetworkCredentials
    {
        get { return new System.Net.NetworkCredential(_userName, _password, _domain); }
    }

    #endregion
```

The same code works fine in our other project. For a new solution Its not working.
Please help what I'm missing out.

Thanks in advance.